# python loop with list and array

Tags: python, loops

I need to loop through ( list and array) as below

```
f=[2,3]
b=np.array([1,2],[2,3])


total=(f[0]*(b[0][0]+b[0][1])+(f[1]*(b[1][0]+b[1][1])
```

I want to do this using loop with sum, because the actual equation is more complicated.

so `total=sum(F*(b+b))`

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to generalise dimensions of an array, you can use the '`:`' index. For example,

```
total = 0
for i in range(2):
    total += f[i]*sum(b[i,:])
```

I'll leave this here as well: [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Comment: no it is not dot or @ multiplication . how I can do it in away that the python will take the first element in the F and understand the b is b from first list  and for second element in F will use the second list

Comment: I edited my answer, I hope this is what you need.